# Simplify php user profile update code

Tags: php

I am making a user profile update php file and I wonder, is there any other ways to simplify this `if` statement code that checks if input is empty or not? Currently code looks like this:

`

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
    $surname = test_input($_POST['surname']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $newPassword = $_POST['newPassword'];
    $newConfirmPassword = $_POST['newConfirmPassword'];

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data = strtolower($data);
        return $data;
    };

    if($password != $_SESSION['password']){
        die('Wrong password, try again!');
    }else{
        if(empty($name) && empty($surname) && empty($newPassword) && empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            die('No changes has been made!');   
        }else if(!empty($name) && empty($surname) && empty($newPassword) && empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            //name update
        }else if(!empty($name) && !empty($surname) && empty($newPassword) && empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            //name and surname update
        }else if(!empty($name) && !empty($surname) && !empty($newPassword) && empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            die('New passwords do not match');
        }else if(!empty($name) && !empty($surname) && empty($newPassword) && !empty($newConfirmPassword)){ 
            die('New password do not match');
        }else if(!empty($name) && empty($surname) && !empty($newPassword) && !empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            //name and passwords update
        }else if(!empty($name) && !empty($surname) && !empty($newPassword) && !empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            //name , password and surname update
        }else if(empty($name) && !empty($surname) && empty($newPassword) && empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            //surname update
        }else if(empty($name) && !empty($surname) && !empty($newPassword) && empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            die('New passwords do not match');
        }else if(empty($name) && !empty($surname) && empty($newPassword) && !empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            die('New passwords do not match');
        }else if(empty($name) && !empty($surname) && !empty($newPassword) && !empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            //surname and password change
        }else if(empty($name) && empty($surname) && !empty($newPassword) && empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            die('New passwords do not match');
        }else if(empty($name) && empty($surname) && empty($newPassword) && !empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            die('New passwords do not match');
        }else if(empty($name) && empty($surname) && !empty($newPassword) && !empty($newConfirmPassword)){
            //password change
        };
    };
?>
```

`

Maybe there is a way to do this with function somehow?

Comment: Before I start please clarify if the `die` commands are only here in MCVE as "placeholder" or they will remain in the final code as well. When you are using the `die` command then the very first step could be that all the `else` after each `die` could be omitted.

Comment: That's what I want, I want to omit the rest of the code if `die` is executed

Comment: Ideally, you should use multiple functions : eg. one for validating your name & surname, one for validating your passwords, one to see if everything is empty, etc. See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752987/simplify-php-user-profile-update-code/35753423#35753423) to get an idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
if($_POST['password'] !== $_SESSION['password']){
    die('Wrong password, try again!');
}
$data['name'] = test_input($_POST['name']);
$data['surname'] = test_input($_POST['surname']);
$passwordConfirmed = $_POST['newConfirmPassword'] === $_POST['newPassword'] && !empty($_POST['newPassword']);
$newPassword = $_POST['newPassword'];
$data = array_filter($data);
if (count($data)===0) { 
   die('No changes has been made!'); 
} 
if (!empty($newPassword) && $passwordConfirmed) {
   //Update password
} else {
   foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
        //Update field. This would work best if your $field variable makes updating easy to code.
       //break; //If you only want to update one field on each request
   }
}
```

This looks slightly smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function who can update a) The name b) The surname c) the password. After that you can do this:

```
if(!empty($name)){
  updateName($name);
}
if(!empty($surname)){
  updateSurname($surname);
}
if(!empty($newPassword) && !empty($newConfirmPassword)){
  if($newPassword == $newConfirmPassword){
    updatePassword($newPassword);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that now!

Answer (score 0):

I would use multiple functions : one to see if no changes are made at all, one to test if the passwords are valid, etc.

#### Example code :

```
function stripName($data) {
    return strtolower(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($data)));
}

function noChanges($name, $surname, $newPassword, $newConfirmPassword) {
    if(empty($name) &&
       empty($surname) &&
       empty($newPassword) &&
       empty($newConfirmPassword)
    ) {
        return 'No changes has been made!';
    }
    return false;
}

function oldPasswordIsInvalid($password) {
    if($password !== $_SESSION['password']){
         return 'Wrong password, try again!';
    }
    return false;
}

function newPasswordIsInvalid($password1, $password2) {
    if(empty($password1) {
        return 'Password must not be empty';
    }
    if(empty($password2) {
        return 'Password confirmation must not be empty';
    }
    if($password1 !== $password2) {
        return 'Passwords do not match';
    }
    return false;
}

function errorFound(
        $name,
        $surname,
        $password,
        $newPassword,
        $newConfirmPassword
) {
    return 
        oldPasswordIsInvalid($password) || 
        noChanges($name, $surname, $newPassword, $newConfirmPassword) || 
        newPasswordIsInvalid($newPassword, $newConfirmPassword);
}

function removeEmptyFieldsFromArray($array) {
    $returnArray = [];
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(!empty($value)) {
            $returnArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $returnArray;
}

session_start();
$name = stripName($_POST['name']);
$surname = stripName($_POST['surname']);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$newPassword = $_POST['newPassword'];
$newConfirmPassword = $_POST['newConfirmPassword'];

if ($errorMessage = errorFound(
        $name,
        $surname,
        $password,
        $newPassword,
        $newConfirmPassword
)) {
    die($errorMessage);
} else {
    $valuesThatNeedToBeUpdated = removeEmptyFieldsFromArray([
        'name' => $name,
        'surname' => $surname,
        'password' => $newPassword
    ]);
    // $valuesThatNeedToBeUpdated is an array that contains
    // only the fields that aren't empty.
    // Fields in this array are the ones that need to be updated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think John Slegers' answer is very good. It is the way how a program should work.

In my opinion it can be implemented even more "elegant" with `exceptions`. The advantage when using `exceptions` is, having nested functions, you do not have to check in each level the return value and pass it through - instead of this you can implement the final flow at only one point and it is well defined.

Think about spend around 33$ for this book [Clean Code by Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882). There are some good ideas. You may not agree with all of them but it gives you really a good guideline how to program.

As John pointed out in his comment try to use multiple functions and give the functions very good names. Be happy you are not a programmer 30 years ago where you had 2 characters for your function and variables names...

It is a very good sign you asked this question because you were not "satisfied" with your version.